# Evaluating $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln^3 (1+x^2)}{1+2x^2} \, dx$ with contour integration

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, analysis, contour-integration, complex-integration

I’m trying to evaluate the following integral through a contour method:

> $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln^3 (1+x^2)}{1+2x^2} \, dx$$

Defining
$$f(z)=\frac{\ln^3 (1+z^2)}{1+2z^2}$$

I’ve tried to use a semi-circular contour from $-R$ to $R$ as the integrand is even and have calculated the residue at $z=\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}$ which gives:

$$\text{Res} \left(f(z),\frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}\right) = \frac{\ln^3 (2)}{2\sqrt{2}} i$$

However, I’m struggling because there are branch cuts that I’m not sure how to deal with here. I can evaluate the related integral:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln (1+x^2)}{1+2x^2} \, dx = -\frac{\pi\ln(6-4\sqrt{2})}{2\sqrt{2}}$$

Since $\ln (1+x^2)=\ln(1+i x)+\ln(2-i x)$ allowing the integral to be separated and each new integral to be integrated along a semi-circle without running into a branch cut. However, I’m not sure about the squared or cubed case.

**EDIT**

With the help of Mathematica, I can determine

> $$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\ln^3 (1+x^2)}{1+2x^2} \, dx = \pi\left(3\sqrt{2}\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{1}{4}\left(2+\sqrt{2}\right)\right)-3\sqrt{2}\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{1}{4+2\sqrt{2}}\right)-6\sqrt{2}\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\ln(2)+\frac{3\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\ln(2)}{\sqrt{2}}+3\sqrt{2}\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{4}\left(2+\sqrt{2}\right)\right)\ln\left(4-2\sqrt{2}\right)+\frac{3\operatorname{Li}_2\left(-2+2\sqrt{2}\right)\ln(2)}{\sqrt{2}}-3\sqrt{2}\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{4+2\sqrt{2}}\right)\ln(2)-3\sqrt{2}\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{1}{4+2\sqrt{2}}\right)\ln\left(2+\sqrt{2}\right)+\frac{3\ln^3(2)}{8\sqrt{2}}-\frac{\ln^3\left(3-2\sqrt{2}\right)}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{\ln^3\left(4-2\sqrt{2}\right)}{\sqrt{2}}-\sqrt{2}\ln^3\left(2-\sqrt{2}\right)-\sqrt{2}\ln^3\left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)-\sqrt{2}\ln^3\left(2+\sqrt{2}\right)-\frac{3\ln(2)\ln^2\left(3-2\sqrt{2}\right)}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{9\ln^2(2)\ln\left(2-\sqrt{2}\right)}{4\sqrt{2}}+\frac{3\ln^2\left(4-2\sqrt{2}\right)\ln\left(2-\sqrt{2}\right)}{\sqrt{2}}+3\sqrt{2}\ln(2)\ln^2\left(2-\sqrt{2}\right)-\frac{75\ln^2(2)\ln\left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)}{4\sqrt{2}}+6\sqrt{2}\ln^2\left(2-\sqrt{2}\right)\ln\left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)-\frac{3\ln\left(\frac{577}{2}-204\sqrt{2}\right)\ln^2\left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)}{2\sqrt{2}}-\frac{3\ln(2)\ln^2\left(2+\sqrt{2}\right)}{\sqrt{2}}+3\sqrt{2}\ln(2)\ln^2\left(3+2\sqrt{2}\right)-\frac{3\ln\left(1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\ln^2\left(3+2\sqrt{2}\right)}{2\sqrt{2}}+\frac{3\ln\left(1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)\ln^2\left(3+2\sqrt{2}\right)}{2\sqrt{2}}+\frac{3\ln^2(2)\ln\left(1393+985\sqrt{2}\right)}{2\sqrt{2}}-\frac{3\ln\left(12-8\sqrt{2}\right)\ln\left(3-2\sqrt{2}\right)\ln\left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)}{\sqrt{2}}+\frac{3\ln(2)\ln\left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)\ln\left(2+\sqrt{2}\right)}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{3\ln\left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)\ln\left(3+2\sqrt{2}\right)\ln\left(136+96\sqrt{2}\right)}{\sqrt{2}}\right)-\frac{\pi^3\left(\ln\left(\frac{577}{8}-51\sqrt{2}\right)-2\ln\left(3-2\sqrt{2}\right)\right)}{4\sqrt{2}}$$

It may be possible to simplify this answer with polylogarithm identities, but I have not yet determined how to.

As @Random Variable suggested, we can use a keyhole contour to determine

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\ln^3 (1+x^2)}{1+2x^2} \, dx = \frac{\pi^3 \ln \left(3-2\sqrt{2}\right)}{\sqrt{2}} - \frac{\pi \ln^3 (2)}{\sqrt{2}} - 6 \pi \underbrace{\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\ln^2 (t^2-1)}{1-2t^2} \, dt}_{I}$$

A method of evaluating $I$ is as follows:
$$I = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln^2 (1-x)}{x^2-2} \, dx + 2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln(1-x) \ln(1+x)}{x^2-2} \, dx + \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln^2 (1+x)}{x^2-2} \, dx + 4 \int_{0}^{1}\frac{\ln^2 (x)}{x^2-2} \, dx - 4 \int_{0}^{1} \frac{\ln (1-x^2) \ln (x)}{x^2-2} \, dx$$
for which each of these integrals, Mathematica is able to evaluate in terms of polylogarithms.

**Are there any further simplifications, rigorous proofs of the integrals Mathematica is able to determine, or any alternate methods at arriving at the answer?**

Comment: If you use the principal branch of the logarithm, then there is a branch cut in the upper half-plane on the imaginary axis from $i$ to $i \infty$.  You'll need to use a keyhole contour that goes around this branch cut. You'll end up with $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\ln^{3}(1+x^{2})}{1+2x^{2}} \, \mathrm dx +6 \pi \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\ln^{2}(t^{2}-1)}{1-2t^{2}} \, \mathrm dt  - 2 \pi^{3} \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{dt}{1-2t^{2}} \, \mathrm dt= 2 \pi i \operatorname{Res}\left[ f(z), \frac{i}{\sqrt{2}}\right]. $$

Comment: @Random Variable Yeah this is basically all I got to- any idea of how to evaluate $\int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\ln^2 (t^2-1)}{1-2t^2} \, dt$?

Comment: I would make the substitution $u = \frac{1}{t}$, but I haven't worked out the details to see if that leads to something manageable.  A thought that comes to mind is to express $\ln^{3}(1+z^2)$ as $\ln^{2}(1+z^{2})\ln(1+z^{2})$ and use two different branches of the logarithm, but that doesn't seem particularly useful here.

Comment: Your $I$ has a cleaner expression: $$\frac{160 L_{8,2}(3)}{3}-36 \sqrt{2} \text{Li}_3(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})-12 \sqrt{2} \text{Li}_2(\sqrt{2}-1) \log (2)+\frac{63 \zeta (3)}{8 \sqrt{2}}+\frac{3 \log ^3(2)}{2 \sqrt{2}}+4 \sqrt{2} \log(\sqrt{2}+1) \log ^2(2)-6 \sqrt{2} \log ^2\left(\sqrt{2}+1\right) \log (2)-\frac{9 \pi ^2 \log (2)}{4 \sqrt{2}}-\frac{1}{3} \sqrt{2} \pi ^2 \log \left(\sqrt{2}+1\right)$$ with only two polylog terms, this is a sense best possible. Here $L_{8,2}(s)$ is the modulus 8 Dirichlet-L function with $\chi(3)=\chi(5)=-1$, you can also write $L_{8,2}(3)$ as polygamma.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer below is addressed to the part of the OP asking "...**rigorous proofs of the integrals Mathematica is able to determine**...". Well, believe it or not, you can actually do all extremely elegantly and even get much more.

**A solution in large steps by Cornel Ioan Valean**

**Key steps:** $1)$ Derive and prepare to use that $\displaystyle \int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\cos(2n\theta)}{\cos^2(\theta)+y^2 \sin^2(\theta)}\textrm{d}\theta=\frac{\pi}{2} \frac{1}{y}\left(\frac{y-1}{y+1}\right)^n, \ y>0$; $2)$ then use the Fourier series of $\log^3(\cos(\theta))$; and finally $3)$ employ all necessary generating functions, which happily are known.

**Your desired result is:**
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\log^3(\cos(\theta))}{\cos^2(\theta)+y^2 \sin^2(\theta)}\textrm{d}\theta=-\frac{1}{8}\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\log^3(1+x^2)}{1+y^2 x^2}\textrm{d}x$$
$$= \frac{\pi}{8}\left(6\zeta(3)-\log(2)\pi^2-4\log^3(2)\right)\frac{1}{y}+\frac{3}{8}\pi(4\log^2(2)+\pi^2)\frac{1}{y}\log\left(\frac{2y}{1+y}\right)$$
$$-\frac{3}{4}\log(2)\pi\frac{1}{y}\log^2\left(\frac{2y}{1+y}\right)-\frac{\pi}{4}\frac{1}{y}\log^3\left(\frac{2y}{1+y}\right)+\frac{3}{4}\pi\frac{\log(y)}{y}\log^2\left(\frac{2y}{1+y}\right)$$
$$-\frac{3}{4}\pi\frac{\log(1-y)}{y}\log^2\left(\frac{2y}{1+y}\right)-\frac{3}{2}\log(2)\pi \frac{1}{y}\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{1-y}{1+y}\right)-\frac{3}{4}\pi \frac{1}{y}\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{1-y}{1+y}\right)$$
$$-\frac{3}{2}\pi \frac{1}{y}\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{2y}{1+y}\right), \ y>0;$$

**And if we want more ...:**
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac{\log^4(\cos(\theta))}{\cos^2(\theta)+y^2 \sin^2(\theta)}\textrm{d}\theta=\frac{1}{16}\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\log^4(1+x^2)}{1+y^2 x^2}\textrm{d}x$$
$$= \frac{\pi}{96}(7\pi^4+24 \log^2(2)\pi^2+48\log^4(2)-288\log(2)\zeta(3))\frac{1}{y}$$
$$-\frac{1}{2}\log(2)\pi(4\log^2(2)+3\pi^2)\frac{1}{y}\log\left(\frac{2y}{1+y}\right)+\frac{\pi^3}{2}\frac{1}{y}\log^2\left(\frac{2y}{1+y}\right)$$
$$-3\log(2)\pi \frac{\log(y)}{y}\log^2\left(\frac{2y}{1+y}\right)+3\log(2)\pi \frac{\log(1-y)}{y}\log^2\left(\frac{2y}{1+y}\right)$$
$$+\frac{3}{2}\log(2)\pi \frac{1}{y}\log^3\left(\frac{2y}{1+y}\right)+\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\log(y)}{y}\log^3\left(\frac{2y}{1+y}\right)-\frac{\pi}{2}\frac{\log(1-y)}{y}\log^3\left(\frac{2y}{1+y}\right)$$
$$
-\frac{\pi}{8}\frac{1}{y}\log^4\left(\frac{2y}{1+y}\right)+\frac{\pi}{4}(12\log^2(2)+\pi^2)\frac{1}{y}\operatorname{Li}_2\left(\frac{1-y}{1+y}\right)+3\log(2)\pi \frac{1}{y}\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{1-y}{1+y}\right)$$
$$+6\log(2)\pi \frac{1}{y}\operatorname{Li}_3\left(\frac{2y}{1+y}\right)-\frac{3}{2}\pi\frac{1}{y} \operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{1-y}{1+y}\right)-3\pi\frac{1}{y} \operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{2y}{1+y}\right)$$
$$
-3\pi \frac{1}{y} \operatorname{Li}_4\left(\frac{y-1}{2y}\right), \ y>0.$$

**The Fourier series used above are**:

$$ \log^3(\cos(x))$$
$$=-\log^3(2)-\frac{1}{4}\log(2)\pi^2-\frac{3}{2}\zeta(3)+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1} \biggr(\left(3\log^2(2)+\frac{\pi^2}{4}\right)\frac{1}{n}$$
$$-3\log(2)\frac{1}{n^2}+\frac{3}{2}\frac{1}{n^3}+6\log(2)\frac{H_n}{n}-3\frac{H_n}{n^2}+3\frac{H_n^2}{n}\biggr) \cos (2 n x),\ -\frac{\pi}{2}<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$$
and
$$\log^4(\cos(x))$$
$$=\log^4(2)+\frac{1}{2}\log^2(2)\pi^2+6\log(2)\zeta(3)+\frac{19}{240}\pi^4$$
$$-\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n-1}\biggr((4\log^3(2)+\log(2)\pi^2+6\zeta(3))\frac{1}{n}-\left(6\log^2(2)+\frac{\pi^2}{2}\right)\frac{1}{n^2}$$
$$+6\log(2)\frac{1}{n^3}-3\frac{1}{n^4}+(12\log^2(2)+\pi^2)\frac{H_n}{n}-12\log(2)\frac{H_n}{n^2}+6\frac{H_n}{n^3}+12\log(2)\frac{H_n^2}{n}$$
$$-6\frac{H_n^2}{n^2}+4\frac{H_n^3}{n}+2\frac{H_n^{(3)}}{n}\biggr) \cos (2 n x),\ -\frac{\pi}{2}<x<\frac{\pi}{2}.$$

**A final note:** All the details of the results above with full solutions will be found in **More (Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series (2023)**, the sequel of **(Almost) Impossible Integrals, Sums, and Series (2019)**.

Comment: Nice general approach!

Comment: @KStarGamer Thank you so much! These results have been waiting for some time to be published (just one step away from the release of the mentioned book).

Answer (score 2):

Set $x=\tan \theta$

Then

$$I=−\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}{\frac{\ln^3 \cos^2 \theta }{1+\sin^2 \theta}}d\theta$$

or

$$I=−\frac{1}{4}\int_{0}^{2\pi}{\frac{\ln^3 \cos^2 \theta }{1+\sin^2 \theta}}d\theta$$

Now you can try to turn the latter into a contour (the unit circle) integral.